# Increase the windows partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

first I had only windows 7 installed then I installed ubuntu 11.04 and gave it alot of space now I want to take free 140GB which on the ubuntu partition and give it to the windows partition how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using a live cd of Ubuntu (or any other distribution, most probably) you can use gparted (sometimes called "gnome partition editor", found in the system/administration menu of the classic desktop) to resize the ubuntu partition to something smaller and then resize the windows partition to take up the space you just freed.

(By the way, you can't use gparted from inside ubuntu because you want to resize the partition you are currently using. That's why i proposed the live cd. You can also use gparted's own live cd , if you don't have an ubuntu one. It can be found here http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)

You can find more info on gparted's documentation (here, for example http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm) but the whole thing is pretty self-explaining once you are in front of gparted.

Comment: The problem is that gparted dosn't let me increase my wndows parition

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what gparted shows you so we can know how your disk is partitioned?

If the partitions are next to each other , what I said above would work. Notice, though, that you First have to resize the ubuntu partition and Then resize the windows one to take the free space left by the ubuntu one.

Comment: Never mind,I found a workaround I made the free space into a new partiton and I can use it on windows and linux.